# Split promise variable into named variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, promise

I have the something like this

```
Promise.all(
  categories.map(category => Collection.find({ category }))
).then(items => {
  return items
})
```

but then I just get an array with the same length as `categories` where each element is an array of the items found in `Collection` within the specific category.

What I want is to return an object where the keys are the categories.

So if my categories are `football`, `volleyball`, and `motorsport`, I want

```
{
  'football': [...],
  'volleyball': [...],
  'motorsport': [...]
}
```

instead of

```
[
  [...],
  [...],
  [...]
]
```

as I have now.

If the number of categories are static, I guess I could do something like this

```
Promise.all(
  categories.map(category => Collection.find({ category }))
).then(([football, volleyball, motorsport]) => {
  return {
    football,
    volleyball,
    motorsport
  }
})
```

Comment: Do you have any field in the categories that contains the `name` of the category?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `items` array has similar order to that of the `categories` array, you can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to combine them to an object using the item, and the category label of the same index:

```
Promise.all(
  categories.map(category => Collection.find({ category }))
).then(items => {
  return items.reduce((o, item, i) => {
    o[categories[i]] = item;

    return o;
  }, {});
})
```

And since you are using ES6, you might want to create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead:

```
Promise.all(
  categories.map(category => Collection.find({ category }))
).then(items => {
  return items.reduce((map, item, i) => map.set(categories[i], item), new Map());
})
```

Comment: Thanks! But isn't it a bit slow to loop through the entire array again with `reduce`? Wouldn't it be possible to split it already in the arguments `.then(.... => ...)`? Also, can I return it as JSON instead of a Map?

Comment: Seems I can just use your first solution to get an object instead of a map :-D

Comment: You need to know the name of each category, and since they are not static, you'll need to loop again. Object vs. map is the reason I wrote **you might want** :)